# Can't Set Custom TextBox text via the properties window in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to set the text in my custom textbox with a variable that I can preset in the visual studio properties window, but the variable keeps ending up empty

```
namespace CustomControlTest
{
    public partial class MyTextField : TextBox
    {
        public MyTextField()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Potato";
            this.Text = GhostText;
            if(GhostText == null)
            {
                this.Text = "Orange";
            }
        }

        public string GhostText { get; set; }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

The textbox text gets set to "Orange" which i don't understand because I have set it to "Something" in the visual studio properties.[image]

I want to be able to set the value of GhostText from her

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: look at `InitializeComponent` method. do you see `GhostText="Something";` code?

Comment: I dont get your question. Ghosttext is null. You set it to Text property so it will be null too. Then it becomes orange because of true condition.whats the problem

Comment: Yes `GhostText="Something"` is in `InitializeComponent`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I set Ghosttext to "Something" in the visual studio properties editor but when I run the code it's null. My question is why is it still null when I set it to "Something" in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you to solve your problem:

```
namespace CustomControlTest
{
    public partial class MyTextField : TextBox
    {
        public MyTextField()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                            
        }    

        private string _ghostText;
        public string GhostText 
        {
            get
            {
                return _ghostText;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Text = value;
                _ghostText = value;
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

and in some other class:

```
var ctr = new MyTextField ();
ctr.GhostText = "Something";
```

Comment: This would set GhostText equal to what ever I put in the text property. Which is not what I want, I want to be able to set the value of GhostText directly from the Properties window. So that I can add my own properties to the Properties window.

Comment: whatever you write in *Text* field of property, it would be in `this.Text` after `InitializeComponent();`. so if you want to set the value of GhostText directly from the Properties window, just write `GhostText = this.Text;`

Comment: Yes but this would use the already created property not my custom property [link](https://gyazo.com/4b571dc340f549507948c9285bd1ad8a)

Comment: OK, I think I miss understood you. please see the edited code.